# Solicitar valores de MAPA que están dentro de otros

Tags: java

mi problema a la hora de hacer los mapas, es que ahora me piden un mapa dentro de otro. Me ejecuta, pero el valor que me da es el mismo. Me hace falta saber las cantidades facturadas por ese vendedor en ese año. Muchas gracias y un saludo.

El enunciado:

Las claves serán los nombres de los vendedores (objetos String).
Los valores serán nuevas estructuras de tipo Map donde:
Las claves serán los años en los que se han vendido productos (objetos Integer).
Los valores serán las cantidades que esos vendedores han facturado durante ese año (objetos Double).

Pongo el código:

```
// Ejercicio 5: clasificación de compras por vendedores y por años
    // --- :------------------------------------------------------------    
    /**
     * Devuelve un Map con las cantidades facturadas por cada vendedor cada año.
     * @return Map donde las claves sean nombres de vendedor y los valores un nuevo Map
     * donde las claves serán años y los valores serán las cantidades facturadas por ese 
     * vendedor en ese año
     */
    public Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>> getComprasPorVendedorYear() {
       
        Map <String, Map<Integer, Double>> facturadas = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Double> facturadas1 = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(TicketCompra cantid : listaTickets){
            facturadas1.put(cantid.getInstante().getYear(), cantid.getImporte());
             facturadas.put(cantid.getVendedor(), facturadas1);
             }
        
        return facturadas; 

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a desmenuzar el problema, te piden: ***vendedor, año, monto***, empezás bien, sabes que toda la info está en ***listaTiquets***, la recorres con el for, pero te olvidas de que no tenemos un único vendedor, ni un único año, y tenemos que tener en cuenta, que la clase ***Map***, si agregas un objeto cuya clave ya existe, reemplaza el anterior por el nuevo, osea jamás tendrias la suma de las ventas de cada año, solo el valor de la última.

La siguiente linea, no está mal, pero ayuda a cometer errores:

```
 for( TicketCompra cantid : listaTickets ) {
```

Con el `for`, recorres el `array` que contiene todos los `tiquet` (***listaTickets***) y tomás uno de estos, bajo el nombre ***cantid*** (***TicketCompra cantid***), cuando uno lee el código, parece que está obteniendo cantidades de algo, es muy fácil cometer errores.
Lo ideal es poner un nombre acorde:

```
 for( TicketCompra tiquet : listaTickets ) {
```

Una vez dentro de este `for`, le pides al `tiquet` el vendedor, el año y la lista de compras.
Creas una variable para guardar la suma de los importes.
Dentro del `for` en que estamos, creas otro `for`, que recorre la lista de compras, le pide a cada compra el precio, y lo suma a la variable que creaste exprofeso.
Luego viene el "alma" del método:

Nota: renombre ***facturadas*** y lo llamé ***comprasVendedorAño***.

```
if( comprasVendedorAño.containsKey( vendedor ) ) {
   if( comprasVendedorAño.get( vendedor ).containsKey( año ) ) {
      importes += comprasVendedorAño.get( vendedor ).get( año );
      comprasVendedorAño.get( vendedor ).put( año, importes );
   }
   else {
      comprasVendedorAño.get( vendedor ).put( año, importes );
   }
}
else {
   Map<Integer, Double> aux = new HashMap<>();
   aux.put( año, importes );
   comprasVendedorAño.put( vendedor, aux );
}
```

Parece complicado pero es fácil de entender.
Si el **Map** contiene al vendedor del tiquet actual (**comprasVendedorAño.containsKey( vendedor )**), pasa al segundo if, que verifica si la key correspondiente al vendedor, contiene el año del tiquet (**comprasVendedorAño.get( vendedor ).containsKey( año )**).
Si la contiene, le pide al Map, el importe asociado a la key del vendedor y la key del año, y se lo suma al importe acumulado.
si no tiene el año, le pide a ***comprasVendedorAño*** el vendedor, y le agrega el nuevo año.
En el caso, que el primer if devuelva un false, osea que ***comprasVendedorAño*** no tenga al vendedor, crea un Map con la dupla año|importes, y luego le agrega a ***comprasVendedorAño*** la dupla vendedor|mapaAuxiliar.
Solo resta devolver ***comprasVendedorAño***.